# Installing addon in 3.0 gives error

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error

I can't install the Simply Cloth addon in blender 3.0 beta. It works fine in blender 2.9.3 but it gives me this error code and i don't reallly know how to fix it. The first time i try it gives me one error and the second time it gives me this other error. I'll write both.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lored\Downloads\blender-3.0.0-beta+v30.b43077ba3a29-windows.amd64-release\blender-3.0.0-beta+v30.b43077ba3a29-windows.amd64-release\3.0\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 387, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\Lored\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\SimplyClothPro\__init__.py", line 37, in register
    properties.register()
  File "C:\Users\Lored\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\SimplyClothPro\properties.py", line 345, in register
    ui_panel.registerIcon()
  File "C:\Users\Lored\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\SimplyClothPro\ui_panel.py", line 935, in registerIcon
    addons_path = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', "addons")
TypeError: user_resource() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

```
  File "C:\Users\Lored\Downloads\blender-3.0.0-beta+v30.b43077ba3a29-windows.amd64-release\blender-3.0.0-beta+v30.b43077ba3a29-windows.amd64-release\3.0\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 387, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\Lored\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\SimplyClothPro\__init__.py", line 37, in register
    properties.register()
  File "C:\Users\Lored\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\SimplyClothPro\properties.py", line 141, in register
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectVertexGroup)
ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass 'SelectVertexGroup'
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.

Answer (score 5):

The Python API changed in 3.0 and the addon needs to be updated. You should report the problem to the addon author so they can fix it.

---

Specifically the second arg to `user_resource` is now keyword-only so this line

```
addons_path = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', "addons")
```

needs to become

```
addons_path = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', path="addons")
```

You can change it yourself if you want but there may be further errors you'll need to fix.