# Positional Argument Error in 3.0

Tags: python, add-on, error

I'm getting this error come up on this line of code, that was working fine in 2.9+ but now isn't for 3.0

```
path = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', os.path.join("presets", "keyconfig"), create=False)
```

The error: TypeError: user_resource() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

I'm seeing this exact error mentioned on Stackoverflow, but failing to understand it or how it works in the Blender environment.

Comment: Use a keyword arg for the path like you do for create: `path=os.path,join(...)`. See [this Q](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/installing-addon-in-3-0-gives-error).

Comment: Fantastic @scurest, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compare the [old docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.93/bpy.utils.html#bpy.utils.user_resource) with the [new docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.html#bpy.utils.user_resource):

```py
bpy.utils.user_resource(resource_type, path='', create=False)
bpy.utils.user_resource(resource_type, *, path='', create=False)
```

You will see an asterisk appeared. It means, that from this point forward, all arguments have to be passed as keyword arguments. So `path` no longer can be passed as a positional argument, you need to change:

```py
path = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', os.path.join("presets", "keyconfig"), create=False)
```

to

```py
path = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', path=os.path.join("presets", "keyconfig"), create=False)
```

[Bare asterisk in function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14301967/1149282)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Note: If you check the [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Python_API) There is a fairly long list of methods that now require keyword arguments.